# Why do some developers neglect -moz- and -o- declaration for transitions?

Tags: css, css-transitions, prefix

Ok, this is a very simple one, yet, I am very curious about it.

Recently I discovered that in some modern (and very well done) design themes developers renounce declaring -moz- and -o- (ok forget about -ms- anyhow) for CSS transforms. So that instead of i.g. having:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.315s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: -webkit-transform 0.315s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: -webkit-transform 0.315s ease-in-out;
        transition:         transform 0.315s ease-in-out;
```

they simply use:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.315s ease-in-out;
        transition:         transform 0.315s ease-in-out;
```

Is there a good reason for this or do they simple not care about other browsers? Is it maybe because also modern Firefox or Opera browser do work with transition without prefix?

I would also love to implement the lighter version 2 in my designs but I am not sure about that. Any explanations from the pros here?

Comment: Well, Firefox and Opera have supported the standard versions for a while now. Only `-webkit` remains relevant for mobile browsers. Unless you want to support very old versions of Firefox and Opera, there's no reason to use those prefixes...

Comment: The answer I hoped for! Cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what browsers and what versions they are aiming for. To the extent of my Webkit experience is that Webkit will likely almost always fall back on the -webkit annotation if the standardized rule fails to parse. I have written quite a few front-ends and I have not seen the newer versions of Firefox use the `moz` annotation, except when it was quite a new feature like `object-fit` or `filters`.

Small word of advice: if you're running Gulp or Grunt, I would advice using `CSS-autoprefixer`. This plugin does the prefixing for you.